# Create choicebox for MS Access 2013 Table cell

Tags: ms-access

One of the columns in my table is Status, and I want it to display 1 of the following 4 options:

> Active, Not Active, Done, New

Is there a way I can create an enumerated list with these 4 choices and then force the user to choose one of those options when they click on a cell in the Status column?

I saw people posted similar questions, but they were all referring to using forms. Is there any way to do this in a table?

Comment: Which version of Access are you using?

Comment: Im using Access 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a lookup field in a table in any Access version 2010 or after. The lookup field can utilize a table, query, or value list as its row source. See [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-lookup-field-87E84CBD-D60C-4473-8A98-3E391C42F239) article for more information.